# Why can't I copy the contents of an XMLDocument to another XMLDocument using TinyXml2?

Tags: c++, xml-parsing, tinyxml2

I do not understand why the below code doesn't work as intended to copy the one element from doc1 to doc2:

```
void test_xml(){
using namespace tinyxml2;
XMLDocument doc1, doc2;
XMLPrinter printer;

doc1.LoadFile("./res/xml/basic.xml");
if(doc1.Error())
    std::cout << doc1.ErrorName();
doc1.Print(&printer);
std::cout << printer.CStr(); // prints "</atag>" without quotes
printer.ClearBuffer();

doc2.InsertFirstChild(doc1.RootElement());
if(doc2.Error())
    std::cout << doc2.ErrorName(); // doesn't run, there's no error
doc2.Print(&printer);
std::cout << printer.CStr(); // prints nothing, no child got inserted to doc2
std::cout << doc2.NoChildren(); //prints "1" meaning we didn't insert anything
}
```

Can someone point out how this can be improved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the TinyXml2 documentation:

> `InsertFirstChild` ... Returns the `addThis` argument or 0 if the node does not belong to the same document.

Basically you can only add a node to a document if the node was manufactured by that document (with `NewElement`, `NewText` etc).

You have to walk through `doc1` creating corresponding nodes as you go (with `ShallowClone`, and adding them to `doc2`.  It appears there is no `DeepClone` to do it all for you.

At http://sourceforge.net/p/tinyxml/discussion/42748/thread/820b0377/, "practisevoodoo" suggests:

```
XMLNode *deepCopy( XMLNode *src, XMLDocument *destDoc )
{
    XMLNode *current = src->ShallowClone( destDoc );
    for( XMLNode *child=src->FirstChild(); child; child=child->NextSibling() )
    {
        current->InsertEndChild( deepCopy( child, destDoc ) );
    }

    return current;
}
```

Comment: I only want to "concatenate", not insert stuff.. is there a way to put the XML CStr()s from the two documents together and then have a third document parse the result without saving to a file first?

Comment: What do you mean by "concatentate"?  If you concatenate two XML files as text, the result is not valid XML (it has two top-level elements).